# drcsim-1.3 viz error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When following the tutorial Visualize and Log Sensor Data from drcsim-1.3 there is an error on viz that says No transform from imu link to pelvis. Plus the robot loads with no hands when running

`roslaunch atlas_utils atlas_position_controllers.launch`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/613/drcsim-1.3-viz-error/) by [jarevalo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/139/jarevalo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-09**:
Can you post the output of the roslaunch scipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

this should be addressed by [issue #72](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/72/torso-imu-has-no-transmission)

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarevalo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/139/jarevalo/) on 2013-01-12**:
Thank you this solved the issue about the IMU